# Existential types in C#?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, existential-type

I'm currently facing a problem in C# that I think could be solved using existential types. However, I don't really know if they can be created in C#, or simulated (using some other construct).

Basically I want to have some code like this:

```
public interface MyInterface<T>
{
    T GetSomething();
    void DoSomething(T something);
}

public class MyIntClass : MyInterface<int>
{
    int GetSomething()
    {
        return 42;
    }

    void DoSomething(int something)
    {
        Console.Write(something);
    }
}

public class MyStringClass : MyInterface<string>
{
    string GetSomething()
    {
        return "Something";
    }

    void DoSomething(string something)
    {
        SomeStaticClass.DoSomethingWithString(something);
    }
}
```

Next I want to be able to iterate through a list of objects that implement this interface, but without caring what type parameter it has. Something like this:

```
public static void DoALotOfThingsTwice(){
    var listOfThings = new List<MyInterface<T>>(){
        new MyIntClass(),
        new MyStringClass();
    };

    foreach (MyInterface<T> thingDoer in listOfThings){
        T something = thingDoer.GetSomething();
        thingDoer.DoSomething(something);
        thingDoer.DoSomething(something);
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile because the `T` used by `MyIntClass` and the one used by `MyStringClass` are different.

I was thinking that something like this could do the trick, but I don't know if there's a valid way to do so in C#:

```
public static void DoALotOfThingsTwice(){
    var listOfThings = new List<∃T.MyInterface<T>>(){
        new MyIntClass(),
        new MyStringClass();
    };

    foreach (∃T.MyInterface<T> thingDoer in listOfThings){
        T something = thingDoer.GetSomething();
        thingDoer.DoSomething(something);
        thingDoer.DoSomething(something);
    }
}
```

Comment: As the type is invariant, no, that's not possible.

Comment: You could wrap the operation in an `Action` and then store those in a list. You can create those actions generically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `DoALotOfThingsTwice` doesn't depend on `T` you can wrap it in an `Action` and store those in the list instead e.g.

```
public static Action DoSomethingTwice<T>(this MyInterface<T> i)
{
    return () =>
    {
        T something = i.GetSomething();
        i.DoSomething(something);
        i.DoSomething(something);
    };
}
```

then

```
var listOfThings = new List<Action>() {
    new MyIntClass().DoSomethingTwice(),
    new MyStringClass().DoSomethingTwice()
};
```

Comment: This would only work if I can do some additional work on that list, right? For example if  `DoSomethingTwice` returned a value, making it `Func<X>` (for some `X` type), then it'd allow me to operate on the list using those `X` values (after evaluating each function). But if I don't do anything else other than `DoSomethingTwice`, then it'd be the same to just call `DoSomethingTwice` on each object separately, without using the list at all, right?

Comment: @gonzaw - Well you can't call `DoSomethingTwice` on each element separately in your `foreach` loop because you can't construct the list you want in the first place. You need to construct some kind of wrapper at the point where you can abstract over `T`. If you need to return a value of `T` to be used inside your `foreach` loop then you have the same problem i.e. you can't describe `T` at all since C# doesn't support existential types as you want. However, what would you do with each `T` inside the loop? You can't meaningfully do anything without knowing `T`.

Answer (score 7):

This is actually possible in a completely type-safe way and without any type casts and without any assumptions about what the interface functions do.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/buneul

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface MyInterfaceFunc {
    void Call<T>(MyInterface<T> obj);
}

public interface MyInterface {
    void Generically(MyInterfaceFunc func);  // this is the key!
}

public interface MyInterface<T> : MyInterface
{
    T GetSomething();
    void DoSomething(T something);
}

public class MyIntClass : MyInterface<int>
{
    public int GetSomething()
    {
        return 42;
    }

    public void DoSomething(int something)
    {
        Console.Write(something);
    }

    public void Generically(MyInterfaceFunc func) {
        func.Call(this);
    }
}

public class MyStringClass : MyInterface<string>
{
    public string GetSomething()
    {
        return "Something";
    }

    public void DoSomething(string something)
    {
        Console.Write(something);
    }

    public void Generically(MyInterfaceFunc func) {
        func.Call(this);
    }
}
public class MyFunc : MyInterfaceFunc {
    public void Call<T>(MyInterface<T> thingDoer) {
        T something = thingDoer.GetSomething();
        thingDoer.DoSomething(something);
        thingDoer.DoSomething(something);
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main(){
        var listOfThings = new List<MyInterface>(){
            new MyIntClass(),
            new MyStringClass()
        };

        foreach (MyInterface thingDoer in listOfThings){
            thingDoer.Generically(new MyFunc());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Not possible directly in C#.

You can either drop type safety and have non-generic base interface and use it for "generic" code:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    object GetSomething();
    void DoSomething(object something);
}

public interface MyInterface<T> : MyInterface
{
    T GetSomething();
    void DoSomething(T something);
}
```

Or use `dynamic` (again no compile time type safety):

```
foreach (dynamic thingDoer in listOfThings)
{
    dynamic something = thingDoer.GetSomething();
    thingDoer.DoSomething(something);
    thingDoer.DoSomething(something);
}
```

Or generate multiple versions of the handler and create (possibly with caching) based on type ([How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)) (Note: that you can't really express "list of arbitrary objects" better than `List<object>` or `List<NonGenericBaseInterface>` or  `List<NonGenericBaseClass>`):

```
foreach (object thingDoer in listOfThings)
{
   // get Do via reflection and create specific version based on 
   // thingDoer.GetType(), than invoke 
   // consider caching "methodForType" in Dictionary by type
   MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("Do");
   MethodInfo methodForType = method.MakeGenericMethod(thingDoer.GetType());
   methodForType.Invoke(thingDoer, null);

}

void Do<T>( MyInterface<T> thingDoer)
{
    T something = thingDoer.GetSomething();
    thingDoer.DoSomething(something);
    thingDoer.DoSomething(something);
}
```

Alternative to reflection is to use Expression tree to build similar code.

Comment: Which one of those approaches would allow me to integrate it with LINQ? For example, if I extract the "generic" code to a function `public static void DoSomethingTwice<T>(MyInterface<T> thingDoer)`, would one of your approaches allow me to map it using `listOfthings.Select(DoSomethingTwice)`? Seems like the approach using `object` would work for this, right?

Comment: @gonzaw yes, non-generic interface would allow for some type safety (`List<MyInterface>`) and use linq `listOfthings.Select(DoSomethingTwice)`, but it will not do dispatch on type of element - so `DoSomethingTwice` would have to work for all types or do dispatch on type in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what's your underlying issue in your actual domain I can't provide a bullet-proof solution. It should be worth the effort that you should look about [what's covariance and contravariance in generic parameters both on interfaces and delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) and give this approach a try refactoring your code.

For now, I believe that this should be a possible solution:

```
public static void DoALotOfThingsTwice()
{
    var listOfThings = new List<object>
    {
        new MyIntClass(), new MyStringClass()
    };

    MyInterface<int> a;
    MyInterface<string> b;

    // During each iteration, check if the thing is a concrete 
    // implementation of your interface MyInterface<T>...
    foreach (object thingDoer in listOfThings)
    {           
        // ...and call MyInterface<T>.DoSomething method depending on 
        // the success of the cast to MyInterface<int> or 
        // MyInterface<string> 
        if ((a = thingDoer as MyInterface<int>) != null)
            a.DoSomething(38);
        else if((b = thingDoer as MyInterface<string>) != null)
            b.DoSomething("hello world");
    }
}
```